# Batch command to open url and fulfill username and password

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm currently opening a local url from batch command (.bat file) like this:

```
@echo off
start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE http://some_local_address:88
```

This is working fine.
The first thing that this site does is to ask for a username and password in a popup window.
Is it possible to pass this information (or at least username) from the .bat file itself, so it is auto-completed in the emerging login window?

(Note that I'm aware you can complete username and password the first time, and "remember credentials", I just want to know if this is possible to pass from command line and how).

Comment: The only way I know of is to pass it through the URL (e.g. user:password@site.com) if the site uses basic auth, but this is disabled by default in newer versions of IE/edge. Beyond that I think you're in saved password / add-on territory

Comment: If you can get your batch file to send keystrokes I don't see why not. Depending on how the page is setup I would imagine you could open the page, send `Tab` until the cursor is in the username box, send the username, send `Tab` again, send the password, send `Enter`.

Comment: You may be able to use `curl.exe`, which allows certain fields to be set. Otherwise, there is the `Selenium` add-on for Firefox, but you won't easily be able to control this from a batch file.

Comment: @BrianC, that is no longer supported.

Comment: @root, any example on how to do that?

Comment: @AFH, any sample on curl? Can't use addons because the idea of this is to have a portable batch which could run from differents computers on the LAN

Comment: There are plenty examples on the web if you search for "auto login with curl", including [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCfB6BP-PN4).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done using a batch file as batch has its own limitations, instead you can you the below VB script.

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "http://TheWebsite"
IE.Visible = True`

While IE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 50
Wend

Set ipf = IE.document.all.username
ipf.Value = "Username" 
Set ipf = IE.document.all.password
ipf.Value = "Password" 
Set ipf = IE.document.all.Submit
ipf.Click 
IE.Quit
```

Update Website name, uname and passwd and then save this as AutoWebsite.vbs

Comment: Thank you. This does not work since the login is not an html form, but a windows prompt instead, which opens up when you hit the website.

Comment: I don't understand windows prompt.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that the login is a little window that pops up asking for username and password, which is not an html form but a browser window instead.

Comment: Use `curl`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password

Comment: I used this but i am unable to login.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

rem wait for the browser to finish loading
timeout /t 10

%SendKeys% "your_username"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "your_password"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"

goto:EOF

@end
// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

thanks to @Varun_ved

source:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403376/automatically-open-a-browser-and-login-to-a-site